# Detect absence of a certain event

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

In the documentation of FlinkCEP, I found that I can enforce that a particular event doesn't occur between two other events using `notFollowedBy` or `notNext`.

However, I was wondering If I could detect the absence of a certain event after a time X. 
For example, if an event **A** is not followed by another event **A** within 10 seconds, fire an alert or do something.

Could be possible to define a FlinkCEP pattern to capture that situation?

Thanks in advance,
Humberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Flink CEP does not support notFollowedBy at the end of a Pattern, there is a way to implement this by exploiting the timeout feature.

The Flink training includes an [exercise](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/long-ride-alerts) where the objective is to identify taxi rides with a START event that is not followed by an END event within two hours. You'll find a solution to this exercise that uses CEP 
[here](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ververica/flinktraining/solutions/datastream_java/cep/LongRidesCEPSolution.java).

The main idea would be to define a Pattern of A followed by A within 10 seconds, and then capture the case where this times out.