# How to generate power off alert using flink-streaming

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

How to generate power off alert using flink-streaming.

e.x: I have a site which sends data to the flink-job via kafka.

Let's say, we received data on 26 April 1992 10:23:52 after that site had some problem it did not send any data. In that case we want to generate an alert saying POWER_OFF.

Is it possible using flink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of heartbeat failure detection is easily accomplished with a `ProcessFunction`. There's an example in the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#example).

You could also do this with CEP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60754081/2000823